# Change Select Button in GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

I am building a CRM. It displays information of customers in a `GridView`. I have Selecting enabled on the `GridView`. And when Selected, it shows a `FormView` with more detailed information on the customer that was selected in the `GridView`. This part is working fine.

I want to make the Customers Name in the `Gridview` to be the select button that displays the `FormView`.

My question is, How do I assign the same functionality that the auto generated Select button has, to any other field in the `GridView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to replace your "Customer Name" column markup with something like this:

```
<asp:ButtonField DataTextField="customerName" HeaderText="Customer Name" ButtonType="Link" CommandName="Select" />
```

This will still show your "Customer Name" data (because of the `DataTextField` attribute), but it is now a `LinkButton` that has the behavior of your previous "Select" button (because of the `CommandName="Select"`).

For more information, see the MSDN documentation on the [ButtonField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.buttonfield.aspx) class.

Comment: Note that "customerName" should be the name of the "Customer Name" column / field in your `GridView`s datasource